# Como usar variaveis de um models em uma view no Django

Tags: html, css, python, django, lógica

Preciso calcular a édia de um boletim escolar onde os dados são preenchidos no Django Admin, gostaria de pegar cada valor fazer a media e jogar em uma tabela na View.

**Código:**

MODEL

```
class Cadastro_Boletim(models.Model):

    ra_aluno = models.ForeignKey(Aluno, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='Nome')
    curso = models.ForeignKey(Curso, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Curso')   # Field name made lowercase.
    nome_disciplina = models.ForeignKey(Disciplina, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Nome_Discplina')
    MB1 = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    SUB1 = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    MB2 = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    SUB2 = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    EX = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    regular = models.BooleanField("Ativo?",default=True)
```

VIEW

```
def boletim(request):    
    contexto = {
        'boletim': Cadastro_Boletim.objects.all()   
    }
    return render(request,"boletim.html", contexto)
```

Dessa forma ele traz tudo que tem no Model, porém não consigo fazer a média com as notas, poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Mas a média entre quais campos?

Comment: Media entre as notas MB1 (1º bimestre) e MB2 (2ºbimestre)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para a média entre os bimestres : MB1 e MB2 , você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
from django.db import AVG, F 
Cadastro_Boletim.objects.aggregate(media_bimestres=AVG(F('MB1')*F('MB2')))
```

Com isso cada elemento terá acessível uma variável "media_bimestres" disponível para acesso.

Comment: Show ! Obrigado Marlysson, só mais uma dúvida, eu consigo fazer esse calculo chamando uma função ?

Comment: @GabrielGeorge Que bom que a resposta foi útil pra você. Poderia marcar a resposta como útil para que outras pessoas com o mesmo problema resolvem-o mais facilmente.

Comment: @GabrielGeorge Sim, consegue. Você que que passe um Cadastro_Boletim ( já filtrado )  e retorne a média daquele em específico?

Tem várias formas pra isso, desde um método no modelo, até um "service" .. qual o ser caso? Seria bom uma nova pergunta para isso. Para ficar isolado as dúvidas.

Comment: Por exemplo, tenho minhas notas, e eu queria chamar uma função calcula_nota, e jogar os valores MB1 e MB2 nessa função para ser realizado todo o calculo da média.

Comment: Você tem alguma modelagem disso? Pois seria adequado haver uma classe NotaBimestral associando uma nota nota, o bimestre e o aluno, com isso podendo agregar vários bimestres para calcular a nota.

O cadastro boletim é responsável por qual conceito do seu sistema?